# Fubini integral with limits depandent on the other limits

Tags: integration, geometry, analysis

$$F(x,y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{c} x^n y &\text{ if } x+y\leq 1, x\geq 0 , y\geq 0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{array} \right.$$ My question is how to calculate $$\iint_R F(x,y)\,dx dy$$ where $R=[0,1]×[0,1]$ knowing that the function is not continous in $R$. Explain with detail please !! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, $$\iint_A F(x,y)\, dx dy = \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^{1-x} F(x,y)\, dy \right) dx = \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^{1-x} x^n y\, dy\right) dx = \int_0^1 x^n \left(\int_0^{1-x} y\, dy \right) dx = \int_0^1 x^n \left.\left(\dfrac{y^2}{2}\right)\right|_{y=0}^{1-x} dx = \int_0^1 x^n \dfrac{(1-x)^2}{2} dx = \int_0^1\dfrac{1}{2} x^n (1-2x+x^2)\, dx = \int_0^1\dfrac{1}{2} (x^n -2x^{n+1} + x^{n+2})\, dx = \dfrac{1}{2}\left. \left(\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} -2\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{n+2} + \dfrac{x^{n+3}}{n+3} \right) \right|_{x=0}^1 = \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \dfrac{1}{n+1} - \dfrac{2}{n+2} + \dfrac{1}{n+3} \right) $$

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with an integral of a discontinuous function, you've to "impose" the integration limits.

Note that, if $R=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $A=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R : x+y\leq 1, x\geq 0, y\geq 0\}$, then $$\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2\setminus A} F(x,y)\, dx dy = 0$$ and therefore $$\iint_R F(x,y)\, dx dy = \iint_A F(x,y)\, dx dy$$ (because $A \subset R$ and $F(x,y)=0 \; \forall (x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2\setminus A$).

So, we have that $$\iint_A F(x,y)\, dx dy = \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^{1-x} F(x,y)\, dy \right) dx$$ (because for every $x\in [0,1]$, it's true that $y$ is between $0$ and $1-x$) and now you can solve this integral normally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I guessed the same too but my problem was when I did it with y . It did not give me the same answer . May be I did something wrong with the calculation .

Comment: Do some drawings always helps to understand